# Error 404 when I try to change language for my Speech-to-Text with IBM-Watson

Tags: python, url, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, speech-to-text

I have to realize a python program and I would like to use watson-IBM services. But I can not change the language in the parameters of the URL (English --> French)

I already read this API doc: https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/speech-to-text?topic=speech-to-text-models&locale=en

This code works (default language):

```py
speech_to_text = SpeechToTextV1(
    iam_apikey='blablablablabla <3',
    url='https://gateway-lon.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api')
```

but not this one

```py
speech_to_text = SpeechToTextV1(
    iam_apikey='blablablablabla <3',
    url='https://gateway-lon.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api/v1/recognize?model=fr-FR_BroadbandModel')
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the API documentation - https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/speech-to-text?code=python

You have mixed service handle object instantiation with the service invocation. The snippet you show is the service handle object instantiation and the url should be something like 'https://gateway-lon.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api' or 'https://gateway-wdc.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api'

When you want to transcribe some audio you use the method `recognize` in your case this would be `speech_to_text.recognize(...)`. So from the service documentation -

```
speech_recognition_results = speech_to_text.recognize(
        audio=audio_file,
        model='fr-FR_BroadbandModel'

    ).get_result()
```